# How to port an android application to blackberry?

Tags: android, blackberry, porting

I am developing apps for ios and android sdk. Is there any tutorial that explains how to port an existing android app to blackberry, and to publish it to the blackberry market?

I have no clue as far as blackberry is concerned. I saw a recent video on RIM playing an android app on an blackberry playbook. Is there is a possiblity of porting an android app in blackberry playbook? Does the porting only narrowed to blackberry playbook or the all other blackberry products?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The android player works on the QNX platform which is what playbook has. You can port your android app to run on the android player fairly easily and test it on the playbook. when the new Blackberry 10 phones are launched, they will run QNX and your ported android app should run on it.

Although the android player has limitations. Among several limitations, one I can recollect is it cannot do C2DM.The others are

It cannot run

1. anything built using the Native Development Kit
2. apps containing only App Widgets
3. apps containing more than one activity tied to the Launcher.
4. any packages which rely on Google Maps
5. in-app billing services,
6. Android's text-to-speech engine

I dont think it is worth spending time and money to port your android app to blackberry devices pre 10 as RIM has announced that they are killing java on blackberry. So best bet is to use android player and port your app to run on it so it works on playbook,blackberry 10 onwards.

Comment: Just because Java will not be used in QNX-based devices, which do not even exist on the consumer market yet other than PlayBook, does not meant that existing Java-based phones will just disappear overnight. Even RIM says that existing phones up to OS7 will still be supported for a long time. That is a big market to ignore if you want to break into the Blackberry community in the near future. It will take time for QNX to take a significant hold.

Answer (score 3):

Porting existing android app to blackberry is explained in below tutorial

http://www.whitesof.com/?q=node/37